# Django admin panel does not have a standard form

Tags: python-3.x, django

Django admin panel does not have a standard form I'm trying to deploy my site on VPS - debian 10, django 3.1, but the admin panel does not have a standard form [see the example in the picture] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JCSH.png)

Comment: Hi, what to you mean by "standard form" ? Do you see admin login form ? If yes, what do you see when logged in ?

Comment: Hi, yes,  i see admin login form, but it looks wrong, for example, no colors, below I attached a picture. Thanks for the help!

Comment: thank you everybody! I solved the problem, the problem was in versions of django 3.1.1. has specifics after adjusting the settings in a new way everything worked # settings.py : STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles')) 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage' # new

Comment: pip install whitenoise

Comment: full answer here: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-static-files

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by standard form? There were changes related to the admin panel in Django 3.1. For example there is a new tab at the left when you are viewing a model, that you can show/hide

Check for the [Django 3.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Вelow I have attached a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's probably related to static files (css, javascript, etc.), as you're putting your site on production. Firstly, you need to check if you configured your STATIC_ROOT correctly. Then, you should configure your web server to serve this folder as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).